# Rollup vite-dts-plugin declaration files without emiting to src

Tags: typescript, vite

I'm trying to bundle types alongside my Vite library, using `vite-plugin-dts`.

When I try to build with `rollupTypes: true` option inside `vite.config.json`, I get the following error:

```
Analysis will use the bundled TypeScript version 5.0.4
*** The target project appears to use TypeScript 5.2.2 which is newer than the bundled compiler engine; consider upgrading API Extractor.
[vite:dts] Internal Error: Unable to determine semantic information for declaration ...
```

By trial and error, I found I can fix this problem by setting `emitDeclarationOnly: true`, in `tsconfig.json`, after which the build step finishes without problems, with `main.d.ts` appropriately bundled, however, it also leads to `.d.ts` files getting emitted into my `src` folder.

I would prefer to not have `.d.ts` files polluting my `src` and instead just bundle types during the build step. Is there any way to do this?